# The right way to receive related data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Here are some models:

- UserModel
- SpecializationModel
- UserSpecializationModel

I need to recieve authorized user's specialization. I can do that:

```
$specializations = UserSpecialization::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Also I can do this through the `UserModel` model using relation `hasMany()` `specializations()`.

When to use first case and the second?

```
$specializations = Auth::user()->specializations();
```

Do I need a model UserSpecializationModel?

Answer (score 1):

In general you don't need `UserSpecilizatonModel`, in most situations you wont access data directly from that table, you'll either do it through user or specialization model.

Check also https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns for accessing data from pivot table.

Comment: Thank you a lot. but I did not get from docs how to binf two models without third

Comment: You can either have a pivot table https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-table-structure or store specialization_id on the users table and you'll have a belongsTo / hasOne. depends what you want to do